# What is a tower?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I am reading James Dugundji's Topology from 1966. In it he describes a tower. But I do not understand completely. 
[image: Tower]

Why is it called a tower?

It seems as though 2.2.b is recursive because the union of any well ordered family of sets will create another well ordered family of sets in $F$; and with any well ordered family of sets, their union is in $F$.

Does that mean towers are infinite?

Also what is the significance of 2.2.c?

If anyone can shed some light on this I will appreciate it.

Comment: Taking $X$ to be an arbitrary non-empty set, and $\varphi(A)=x$ a constant map, then I think $\mathscr F=\{\emptyset,\{x\}\}$ is a $\varphi$-tower: Clearly $\emptyset\in\mathscr F$, and for any $A\in F$, $A\cup\{\varphi(a)\}=\{x\}\in\mathscr F$. And all subsets of $\mathscr F$ are totally ordered, and their union is either empty (if they don't contain $\{x\}$) or $\{x\}$ (if they do contain $\{x\}$), which are both in $\mathscr F$. Clearly this $\mathscr F$ is finite, as it has exactly two elements. So apparently $\varphi$-towers need not to be infinite.

Comment: This is a variation of the concept used by Halmos in “Naive set theory” for proving Zorn’s lemma from the axiom of choice, which possibly goes back to Zermelo.

Comment: @celtschk, thank you. If the tower satisfies 2.2.b does it become infinite?
Using your $\mathscr{F}$, let the set $A_\alpha \text{ where } \alpha\in\mathbb N$ be a family of sets $F = \{A_1, A_2, A_3\}$, where $A_1=\{\emptyset\}, A_2=\{x\}, A_3=\{\emptyset, x\}$. The set $F$ is totally ordered, under the relation $R=\{(A_1,A_2),(A_2,A_3) \}$ then the union of all the sets is in $\mathscr F$. So $\cup A_\alpha = \{\emptyset, x\}$ and that is already in these set $\mathscr F$. Cool makes sense.

Comment: A tower is called a tower because it consists of some fundamental elements and each step along the way to the greatest element?

Comment: what means that $\varphi$ is fised map? means for some $x\in X$ , $\varphi:A\mapsto x$ for all $A\in\mathscr F$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is like the recursive construction of the ordinals for ZF set theory.  Rule a is including 0, rule b is including limits and rule c includes successors.  Both b and c are recursive.  It's not required that a linear subset of F is well ordered.   For example, let F be all subsets of R and phi map A to sup A if it exists, otherwise to 0.  With recursive definitions it is common to require the set to be the smallest set closed under the recursion and containing the base elements such as 0.  For the example given, the smallest would be the tower of just the empty set.  Is there a smallest  infinite tower that's not well ordered?

Comment: I can't even think of an infinite set that is not well ordered. Is the family of sets $A$ such that $A = \{x \in A_\alpha : \alpha \in \mathbb N, x = 1\}$ well ordered? $A$ is just $\{\{1\}, \{1\}, \{1\}, \{1\}, ... \}$. It seems like there is no order to it, but it is a family of sets, so there is a first element $A_1 = {1}$ and a successor $A_2={1}$. What is an infinite unorderd set?

Comment: Is the set $\mathscr P(\mathbb N)$ infinite and not a well order?

Comment: @Tsangares.  A is not infinite.  It has just on element.  The order { (x,x) : x in S }, the trivial order, can be considered as S having no partial order.

Comment: @Tsangares.  Yes P (N) is infi ite

Comment: @Tsangares.  Yes P (N) is infinite and not well ordered by inclusion but not a tower without a map from the subsets into the integers.